# ERROR: column "FLAT" does not exit. Line 1. SELECT UPPER(FLAT). Kindly fix the trigger

Tags: trigger, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_fct_tri_sv_tab_temp() 
RETURNS trigger 
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  n.FLAT := UPPER(n.FLAT);
  RETURN NEW;
end
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER;


CREATE TRIGGER tri_sv_tab_temp
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sv_tab_temp FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_tri_sv_tab_temp();
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The updated or inserted row is referenced using the `new` record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_fct_tri_sv_tab_temp() 
RETURNS trigger 
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  new.FLAT := UPPER(new.FLAT);
  RETURN NEW;
end
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Comment: I have tried to insert data into the table sv_tab_temp, it seems okay.

 

I am asking developer to further checking. Thanks.